# New to Solr: Response to query includes document contents

Tags: solr

I am relatively new to Solr, and have managed to index PDF documents.

But when I query solr I get responses including the the document contents. Is there a way to control what will be in the response?

How do i do that, if possible?

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the fields within your response through the fl parameter. You can have a look at the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl).